# Unity3d level design in blender or in unity?

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, build, blender

Hello I have a quick question about making rooms and hallways in my game. Now I could easily create hallways and rooms with ProBuilder in Unity but im not really sure if this is efficient because of the amount of batches it produces and how it decreases my performance (fps). Now my question is should I rather make the rooms and hallways inside of blender to have better performance and just import them into unity or should I just use unity instead and find a way to reduce the batch size for example by combining meshes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my experience, modelling or level design on unity could be an option if you don't have other 3D software background.

However, if you know Blender, Maya or Cinema4D, you should create the basic scene in those modelling software. In this case, you can highly optimise your polygon freely, like merging duplicated vertex, reducing polygon..etc.

For performance, you need to focus on few things:

1. triangles count
2. vertex count
3. draw calls (how many individual meshes, less is better)

You don't have to follow the traditional modelling way in most of case. As long as you can create the 3D shape with minimal triangles, it's the best model for game engine.

In general, you only need to work on the lighting and shading in Unity side.
You don't have to spend too much time on blender lighting, as it will always look far different result on unity.

Instead, you should learn and try baking the scene in Unity. If you have experience in Blender rendering, it won't be too difficult to move to Unity light map baking solution.

PS: the last thing, just be careful some basic settings, like, setting the render mesh as static object in order to get the effect of baking.

Comment: If I am modeling characters and props I would indeed use Blender or any other 3D modeling software. But for rooms and hallways, I would personally stick with ProBuilder since it is built in the editor in Unity and it is thus very easy to alter and adjust while playtesting.

Comment: as long as you familiar with the tool, that's the best and fastest solution.
ProBuilder is good for prototyping, but still, I recommended that you can export it to Blender for further optimisation in final version. It's important to remove all invisible polygons, considering low-end mobile or Quest VR development..etc.